# How make Excel arbitrary pivoting in MS SQL 2017 (cross join + loops)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, pivot, pivot-table

Would you help me please, to solve the task below in SQL (MS SQL Server 2017). It is simple in Excel, but seems very complicated in SQL.

There is a table with clients and their activities split by days:

```
client  1may 2may 3may 4may 5may other days
client1 0    0    0    0    0    ...
client2 0    0    0    0    0    ...
client3 0    0    0    0    0    ...
client4 1    1    1    1    1    ...
client5 1    1    1    0    0    ...
```

It is necessary to create the same table (the same quantity of rows and columns), but turn the values into new one according to the rule:
Current day value =

A) If all everyday values during a week before the day, including the current one = 1, then 1

B) If all everyday values during a week before the day, including the current one = 0, then 0

C) If the values are different, then we leave the status of the previous day (if the status of the previous day is not known, for example, the Client is new, then 0)

In Excel, I do this using the formula: = IF (AND (AF2 = AE2; AE2 = AD2; AD2 = AC2; AC2 = AB2; AB2 = AA2; AA2 = Z2); current_day_value; IF (previous_day_value = ""; 0; previous_day_value )).

The example with excel file [is attached.](https://yadi.sk/i/PMqsS8DAnXj4LA)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add what brand of sql you're using? Plus the tables & schema you have to work with?

Comment: Richard, thank you for the response. I use MS SQL Server 2017 (SQL Server Management Studio). What do you mean under tables and schema I use?

Answer (score 3):

First thing, it's NEVER a good idea to have dates as columns.

So step #1 transpose your columns to rows. In other world to build a table with three columns

````
```
client  date Value
client1 May1    0
client1 May2    0
client1 May3    0
....    ...     ..
client4 May1    1 
client4 May2    1 
client4 May3    1 
....    ...     ..
```
````

step #2 perform all the calculations you need by using the date field.

Comment: David, thank you very much for advise. The data structure you showed is my initial data. But I converted it into pivot table to higlight the days where clients were not active. Because it's important to me to analyse the activity in each day. E.g. client was active only in 1may and 4may. I have only to rows in the table with records of 1may and 4may. But I need the records about the client activity in each day. Therefore I use: 1may = 1, 2may (occurs after pivoting the table) = 0, 3may = 0, 4may = 1, 5may = 0, 6may = 1 ets. Is there another method to higlight the days client was not active?

Comment: David, I have restructured the table the way you advised via cross join. Would you prompt me the next steps. Should I use loop for the solving the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you put **always the status of the previous day, in any case** (except null).

So, i would do something like this (oracle syntax, working in sql server too), supposing the first columns is 1may

```
Insert into newTable (client, 1may,2may,....) select (client, 0, coalesce(1may,0), coalesce (2may,0), .... from oldTable;
```

Anyway me too i believe is not a good practice to put the days as columns of a relational table.

Comment: Massimo, thank you for the answer to re-group the data. I don't put always the status of the previous day, in any case but null. Consider the Excel-example (cell FE3: calculated value in the current day != cell BO3: initial value in the previous day).

Comment: So the rule you've written in your post in points A,B,C is wrong. Point C should be  If the values are different, then we leave the status of the **current** day. Can you clarify the exact rules, please, expecially put in evidence when you use let's say old table values or already computed values

Comment: Massimo, I use in the condition C - previous day and not the current day, since I want to save status Quo, if client behaviour is unstable. I want to make client behaviour smoother. If use current day, this: may=1, may2 = 0, may3 = 1, may4 =0, may5 = 1 will result the same values. But using my logic, it keeps the last value, when the values were stable during the week.

Comment: what i was meaning is, if for current_day_value and previous_day_value you mean the values coming from the 'old' table or you mean the values already computed in the new table. From the excel it look like you're using the computed values but it's a bit unclear to me

Comment: In Excel there are 2 tables: initial data - is in the left, calculated date is in the right. If the data is unstable we take the values from the initial table. New table should be computed from zero.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to struggle with this because most brands of SQL don't allow "arbitrary pivoting", that is, you need to specify the columns you want to be displayed on a pivot - Whereas Excel will just do this for you. SQL can do this but it required dynamic SQL which can get pretty complicated and annoying pretty fast.

I would suggest you use sql just to construct the data, and then excel or SSRS (As you're in TSQL) to actually do the visualization.

Anyway. I think this does what you want:

```sql
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-04'),1)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-05'),1)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-06'),1)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-07'),0)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-08'),0)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-09'),0)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-10'),1)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-11'),1)
    ,   ('Client 1',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-12'),1)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-04'),1)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-05'),0)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-06'),0)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-07'),1)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-08'),0)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-09'),1)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-10'),0)
    ,   ('Client 2',CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-11'),1)
    ) x (Client, RowDate, Value)
)

SELECT 
    Client
,   RowDate
,   Value
,   CASE 
        WHEN OnesBefore = DaysInWeek THEN 1
        WHEN ZerosBefore = DaysInWeek THEN 0
        ELSE PreviousDayValue
    END As FinalCalculation
FROM (
    -- This set uses windowing to calculate the intermediate values
    SELECT 
        *
        
        -- The count of the days present in the data, as part of the week may be missing we can't assume 7
        -- We only count up to this day, so its in line with the other parts of the calculation
    ,   COUNT(RowDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Client, WeekCommencing ORDER BY RowDate) AS DaysInWeek
        
        -- Count up the 1's for this client and week, in date order, up to (and including) this date
    ,   COUNT(IIF(Value = 1, 1, NULL)) OVER (PARTITION BY Client, WeekCommencing ORDER BY RowDate) AS OnesBefore
    
        -- Count up the 0's for this client and week, in date order, up to (and including) this date
    ,   COUNT(IIF(Value = 0, 1, NULL)) OVER (PARTITION BY Client, WeekCommencing ORDER BY RowDate) AS ZerosBefore
    
        -- get the previous days value, or 0 if there isnt one
    ,   COALESCE(LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Client, WeekCommencing ORDER BY RowDate), 0) AS PreviousDayValue
    FROM (
        -- This set adds a few simple values in that we can leverage later
        SELECT
            *
        ,   DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DW, RowDate) + 1, RowDate) As WeekCommencing
        FROM Data
    ) AS DataWithExtras
) AS DataWithCalculations
```

As you haven't specified your table layout, I don't know what table and field names to use in my example. Hopefully if this is correct you can figure out how to click it in place with what you have - If not, leave a comment

I will note as well, I've made this purposely verbose. If you don't know what the "OVER" clause is, you'll need to do some reading: https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/. The gist is they do aggregations without actually crunching the rows together.

Edit: Adjusted the calculation to be able to account for an arbitrary number of days in the week

Comment: Richard, thank you so much for so detailed answer. I've rereaded your answer for several times and got a lot from it. But the result is not what I desire. Desirable results for Client 1: 4may - 0; 5may - 0 (there are not 7 days with equal values and we get the value we calculated yesterday) 6may - 0, 7may - 0, 8may - 0, and so on, while the initial values durig a week will be equal to 1.

Comment: Ah, so days can be missing from the set? Could you post some example data in the main body of your question in the "Client, RowDate, Value" format with an extra column of what the final calculation should be?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much to everyone, especially to David and Massimo, which prompted me to restructure the data.

```
--we join clients and dates each with each and label clients with 'active' or 'inactive'
with a as (
select client, dates
from (select distinct client from dbo.clients) a
cross join (select dates from dates) b
)
, b as (
select date
      ,1 end active
      ,client
from clients a
join dbo.dates b on a.id = b.id

)
select client
      ,a.dates
      ,isnull(b.active, 0) active
into #tmp2
from a
left join b on a.client= b.client and a.dates = b.dates


--declare variables - for date start and for loop
declare @min_date date = (select min(dates) from #tmp2);
declare @n int = 1
declare @row int = (select count(distinct dates) from #tmp2) --number of the loop iterations

--delete data from the final results
delete from final_results

--fill the table with final results

--run the loop (each iteration = analyse of each 1-week range)
while @n<=@row

begin

with a as (
--run the loop 
select client
      ,max(dates) dates
      ,sum (case when active = 1 then 1 else null end) sum_active
      ,sum (case when active = 0 then 1 else null end) sum_inactive
from #tmp2
where dates between dateadd(day, -7 + @n, @min_date) and dateadd(day, -1 + @n, @min_date) 
group by client
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[final_results]
           (client
           ,[dates]
           ,[final_result])

select client
      ,dates
      ,case when sum_active = 7 then 1 --rule A
       when sum_inactive = 7 then 0 -- rule B
       else
       (case when isnull(sum_active, 0) + isnull(sum_inactive, 0) < 7 then 0
       else 
           (select final_result 
           from final_results b 
           where b.dates = dateadd(day, -1, a.dates) 
           and a.client= b.client) end
       ) end
from a

  set @n=@n+1

end

if object_id(N'tempdb..#tmp2', 'U') is not null drop table #tmp2
```